# Trying to move a header and can't get the code correct

Tags: html, header

Can anyone give me a help with code? I'm trying to move the `h3` header to the right side of the page and cannot seem to get it to move. The attached picture is of where it is now and where I would like it to be.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en"><head>
   <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
      
   <link href="https://www.carymcclure.com/public_html/favicon.ico?v=1" rel="shortcut icon" 
   type="image/x-icon" />
          
   <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
   <meta name="theme-color" content="004c30">
     
    <style>
 
    body {
    
    background-image: url("../img/ivyt.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 1930px;
    height: 8867px;
      }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Cary McClures' Portfolio</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
  
    <body>
    <a href="../pdf/IVY Academic Transcript.pdf" style="position: absolute; left: 1608px; z-index: 
    50; width: 248px; top: -86px; height: 233px;"><img style="float:right;margin- 
    top:250px;position: relative;" 
         src="../img/ivy logo.gif" width="150" height="150" alt="email"></a>
    
    <h3> Click Logo to Download</h3>
    <h3 style="color: white;"></h3>
    

    
    
    
   </body>  


   </html>
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking your next question :)..

Answer (score 0):

Apply a `float: right;` to the `<h3>` element

```css
body {
background-image: url("../img/ivyt.gif");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 1930px;
height: 8867px;
}

h3 {
float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en"><head>
       <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
          
       <link href="https://www.carymcclure.com/public_html/favicon.ico?v=1" rel="shortcut icon" 
       type="image/x-icon" />
              
       <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
       <meta name="theme-color" content="004c30">
         
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Welcome to Cary McClures' Portfolio</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="../css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        
      
        <body>
        <a href="../pdf/IVY Academic Transcript.pdf" style="position: absolute; left: 1608px; z-index: 
        50; width: 248px; top: -86px; height: 233px;"><img style="float:right;margin- 
        top:250px;position: relative;" 
             src="../img/ivy logo.gif" width="150" height="150" alt="email"></a>
        
        <h3> Click Logo to Download</h3>
        <h3 style="color: white;"></h3>
        
    
        
        
        
       </body>  
    
    
       </html>
```

Comment: that did the trick thanks so much